# Exporting Crystal Report to TextFile in C#.Net

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am trying to Export A Crystal Report using C#.Net, but unfortunately I'm having and Error that I specified few lines per page. Even though I already specified a large amount of lines. Can You help me regarding this? Please see my code below for reference.

Thank you.

```
   void XportZ()
      {
          try
          {


            cryRpt.Load(@"D:\Arnie Files\Projects\BIR E-journal\ZTapeReport_PwdAdj_v2.1.rpt");
            cryRpt.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection("FA17083", "MyDB", "sa", "qwerty");
            cryRpt.SetParameterValue(0, dt_BusinessDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
            cryRpt.SetParameterValue(1, "☺" + txt_PosID.Text + "☺");

            ExportOptions.CreateTextFormatOptions().CharactersPerInch = 60;
            ExportOptions.CreateTextFormatOptions().LinesPerPage = 100;
            cryRpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.Text, @"D:\_AAAAAA\Zreading" + txt_PosID.Text + dt_BusinessDate.Value.ToString("MMddyyyy") + ".txt");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            hasError = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            cryRpt.Dispose();
            cryRpt.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? and have you tried changing the LinesPerPage setting and run the code??

Comment: Hi Sujith, the error message says "Error detected by export DLL. Too few lines per page specified." . Yes, I already change the lines per page. I came to the point that I put 99999999 but still, I have the same error message.

Comment: Were you able to see the data loaded in report when you view or preview??

Comment: Yes. I am able to see the data on the reportview but I dont need that. I just need to export this crystal report to textfile. that's all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the ExportToDisk option automatically overrides the linesPerPage. Try doing Report.Export and that should work.